# Prove that the diagonals of a rhombus are orthogonal.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve some of the problems in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis book. On the section about analytic geometry, the following problem is stated:

> Prove that the diagonals of a rhombus are orthogonal.

Since the idea was to use complex analysis tools to solve it, I came up with the following.

I take any arbitrary rhombus and draw it on the complex plane. After this, I re-orient it such that one of the corners is lying on the intersection of the real and imaginary axis and one of the diagonals is on the imaginary axis.
Relating one of the sides of the rhombus with the imaginary number $z$, I obtain the following scenario:
[image]

Recalling that the reflection about the imaginary axis is given by $z \to -\overline{z}$.

Using this construction, if indeed the diagonals are orthogonal this would mean that $\frac{z -\overline{z}}{z +\overline{z}}$ is purely imaginary (since multiplying by $i$ results in a $90^\circ$ rotation in the complex plane). To show this, I do
$$
\overline{\left(\frac{z -\overline{z}}{z +\overline{z}}\right)} = \frac{\overline{z} -\overline{\overline{z}}}{\overline{z} +\overline{\overline{z}}} = \frac{\overline{z} -z}{\overline{z} + z} = - \left(\frac{z -\overline{z}}{z +\overline{z}}\right)
$$
And since
\begin{align}
z = a+ib \text{ is purely imaginary }  \iff  a=0 \iff a =-a \iff a -ib = -a-ib \iff \overline{z} = -z
\end{align}
this concludes the solution.

Is my solution correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, since everything is hapening in upper plane there is no conjugation. Also don't understand how you got those sides.

Comment: What is this quantity $\frac{z -\overline{z}}{z +\overline{z}}$?

Comment: @Aqua, I got the sides by using that the reflection about the imaginary axis of a complex number $z$  is given by the negative of the conjugate. I understand this is because if $z = a+ib$, then $-a+ib = -\overline{z}$ gives the same number but with opposite sign real part.

Comment: And by $\frac{z -\overline{z}}{z +\overline{z}}$ I denote the complex number such that when I multiply it with $z + \overline{z}$ it results in $z -\overline{z}$.

Comment: Also you use that diagonal is angle bisector. Can you use that fact?

Comment: I don't think this proof is OK since you already actually use the fact that diagonals are perpendicular by using reflections.

Comment: Would showing that a rhombus is a parallelogram be sufficient to justify the construction using reflection?

Comment: No, because diagonals in partalellogram are in general not perpendicular.

Comment: Oh, no. I didn't mean to imply that it was sufficient to prove the entire thing. What I meant was that, if I arbitrarily choose some side of the rhombus to be $z$, and I move one of the diagonals to fit with the imaginary axis, using the fact that a rhombus is also a parallelogram would justify that the opposing side has to be $-\overline{z}$, right? And from there (taking into account the correct implication pointed out in the answers), I think the rest of the solution should hold. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially right. There's one problem with

> if indeed the diagonals are orthogonal this would mean that ... is
> purely imaginary

Here what you want is the converse:

> if ... is purely imaginary then the diagonals are orthogonal

You might try an alternative proof using $z$ and $z+e^{i\theta}z$ for the first two edges of the rhombus.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm assuming $\iff$ when I only know $\implies$. But can I prove that this statement is an "if and only if", or does this not go both ways?

Comment: It goes both ways, so long as the ratio isn't $0$, that is, so long as $z$ isn't real, which you can clearly assume.

Comment: Is this really correct? @saulspatz

Comment: @Aqua Well, I think so, certainly.  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: He use reflection for sides which implictly means he used orthogonalty. @saulspatz

Comment: @Aqua No, it just assumes the sides are equal, like in the definition of a rhombus.

Comment: How is then $-\overline{Z}$, which is means reflection across real axsis and then reflection across origin, just one side with equal distance. It is very specific side which we get by implictly use of orthogonalty. @saulspatz

Comment: @Aqua Surely you recall that $|z|=|\overline{z}|$

Comment: See my answer @saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

You are to much relaying on a picture. You assume that $D$ and $B$ are symmetric to imaginary axsis (since you wrote $w= -\overline{z}$) which authomaticly means $AC\bot BD$ (since $C$ lies on imaginary axsis) which is to be prove. So your proof is not correct.

[image]

Correct way is to say $AD =w$ and we know $|w|=|z|$. Then we need to see that $\displaystyle{z+w\over z-w}$ is imaginary number, i.e. $${z+w\over z-w}= -\overline{\Big({z+w\over z-w}\Big)}$$

Comment: I think this last part can then be shown by doing $$
-\overline{\left(\frac{z+w}{z-w}\right)}=\frac{\overline{w}+\overline{z}}{\overline{w}-\overline{z}}=\frac{|w|^2+\overline{z}w}{|w|^2-\overline{z}w}= \frac{|z|^2+\overline{z}w}{|z|^2-\overline{z}w}=\frac{\overline{z}(z+w)}{\overline{z}(z-w)}=\frac{z+w}{z-w}
$$ right? Assuming $z,w \neq0$ to begin with.

Comment: Also, what I wanted to know is if somehow I could "salvage" my solution using something similar to your method here. Using your diagram as a reference, if I just denote the sides of the rhombus as $z$ and $w$ (like you do), I can _choose_ to put the diagonal on the imaginary axis (without assuming anything else about the position of $w$ respect ot $z$ this time). 

As you pointed out in the comments earlier, If I know that the diagonal bisects the angle $\arg\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)$, then I can justify that $-\overline{z} = w$ and continue the solution as I did. Correct?

Comment: But my question is, if I know that every rhombus is additionally a parallelogram, is this sufficient to show that in the construction detailed above $-\overline{z}=w$? I believe this is enough (like the case where I previously know the bisection to be true) but I'm not sure. Could you tell me if I'm correct on this line of reasoning?

Comment: No, it make no difference. You would still use reflection. And actually you would not use that it is paralelogram at all.

Comment: Ok, but at least using that the diagonal bisects does work to justify that $-\bar{z}=w$. So if I can show that beforehand, then the original solution should be "saved", right?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile preparing solution with "pure" complex properties, I come to one decision, which worthy, imho, to be here.

1)
Let's take $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ complex numbers in opposite clockwise direction,  which gives us rhombus.  We can construct rhombus sides by $a=z_3-z_2$ and $b=z_2-z_1$ and diagonals by $d_2=b+a$ and $d_1=a-b$. If we consider scalar product for diagonals, we have:
$$d_1 \cdot d_2= (a-b) \cdot (a+b)= (a_1-b_1)(a_1+b_1)+(a_2-b_2)(a_2+b_2)=\\=
a_1^2-b_1^2 + a_2^2-b_2^2 = |a|^2-|b|^2=0$$
In one hand it's zero because we are in rhombus, but on another hand this give diagonals perpendicularity.

Second solution coming. Hope.

**Addition.**

2)
As promised lets look on slight different solution. Again we take complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ and construct sides and $a=z_3-z_2$ and $b=z_2-z_1$ and diagonals by $d_2=b+a$ and $d_1=a-b$. For 2 complex numbers we know, that division argument is difference between numerator and denominator arguments i.e. $\Im \frac{d_1}{d_2}=\Im{d_1}-\Im{d_2}$. So let's calculate now complex numbers division:
$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{1}{|a-b|^2}\left(a+b  \right)\left(\overline{a-b}  \right)=\frac{1}{|a-b|^2}\left( |a|^2-|b|^2+\overline{a}b-\overline{b}a \right)=\\=\frac{1}{|a-b|^2}\left( |a|^2-|b|^2+\overline{a}b-\overline{\overline{a}b} \right)=\frac{1}{|a-b|^2}\left( |a|^2-|b|^2+i2\Im(a\overline{b}) \right)$$

As we are in rhombus, then we have $|a|^2-|b|^2=0$ and we get, that division of rhombus diagonals is pure imaginary complex number, so angle between diagonals is right angle.